# Why is the receive () external payable not acting as a fallback?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have this simple code in remix.ethereum

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.1;

contract SimpleWallet {
    
    address owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not allowed");
        _;
    }

    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to, uint _amount) public onlyOwner {
        _to.transfer(_amount);
    }
    
    receive () external payable {
        
    }
    
}
```

I try to deploy the contract with value of 10 eth in the js virtual machine using an address that has 100 eth

But I receive this

```
[vm]from:0xca3...a733cto:SimpleWallet.(constructor)value:10000000000000000000 weidata:0x608...c0033logs:0hash:0xc83...a1795
creation of SimpleWallet errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Why is that happening? The address has 100 eth, and the receive fallback function is defined, Shouldnt my contract be simply deployed with 10eth that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a contract, it doesn't call a fallback. It calls the constructor. If you want to be able to send ETH with the creation of your contract, you need to mark the contructor as payable, like this:

```
constructor() public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```